# Как прервать цикл в генераторе строки

Tags: python-3.x

Не могу понять как можно остановить итерацию указав значения остановки.

```
c = 0
cycle_list = [el if c > 10 else print(el) for el in cycle('ABC')]
```

Comment: `[el for el in cycle('ABC') if c > 10]` но `else print(el)` просто так не засунуть (потому что получится страшная каша кода, что-то вроде такого: `[el for el in cycle('ABC') if (lambda el, c: True if c > 10 else print(el))(el, c)]`). Проще это в обычном цикле сделать

Comment: Да, но условие именно прервать цикл в генераторе списка

Comment: Условие прерывает цикл: `[el for el in cycle('ABC') if c > 10]`